# using the title to get data from the database codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I made a code using codeigniter to get the data by the title of the topic. my code is.

the controller

```
public function viewTopic($category, $title){
        $data['topic'] = $this->Setting->get_dataNew('*', 'community_topics', 'WHERE title="'.str_replace('-', ' ', urldecode($title)).'"');
}
```

the link is like this one.

```
/community/questions/ما-هو-المجتمع-؟
```

The problem is when I added a special characters to the title like - or () the query not working, is there is a way to fix it ?

Comment: try by setting `$config['permitted_uri_chars']=''` in your `config.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using the - to remove the spaces it will not be possible, unless you used different symbol for it, codeigniter filters all special characters to prevent the sql injection attacks, however, you can add column named urlSlug, and store the exact value of the slug in it, so when you query next time, it will be

```
public function viewTopic($category, $title){
        $data['topic'] = $this->Setting->get_dataNew('*', 'community_topics', 'WHERE urlSlug="'.$title.'"');
}
```

We are using the same for the Arabic version of the website, and it is working perfectly,
also don't forget you will need to add the list of the permitted characters to 
`$config['permitted_uri_chars']=''` to avoid any future error.

Comment: That's genius! Thanks.